# Prob. 10 (d), Sec. 19 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How to show that this map is open?

Tags: general-topology

Here's Prob. 10, Sec. 19 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $A$ be a set; let $\{X_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of spaces; and let $\{ f_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of functions $f_\alpha \colon A \to X_\alpha$.
>
> (a) Show there is a unique coarsest topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $A$ relative to which each of the functions $f_\alpha$ is continuous.
>
> (b) Let $$\mathcal{S}_\beta = \left\{ \ f_\beta^{-1}(U_\beta) \ \colon \ U_\beta \mbox{ is open in } \ X_\beta \ \right\},$$ and let $\mathcal{S} = \bigcup \mathcal{S}_\beta$. Show that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for $\mathscr{T}$.
>
> (c) Show that a map $g \colon Y \to A$ is continuous relative to $\mathscr{T}$ if and only if each map $f_\alpha \circ g$ is continuous.
>
> (d) Let $f \colon A \to \prod X_\alpha$ be defined by the equation
> $$ f(a) = \left( f_\alpha(a) \right)_{\alpha \in J};$$
> let $Z$ denote the subspace $f(A)$ of the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. Show that the image under $f$ of each element of $\mathscr{T}$ is an open set of $Z$.

Now parts (a), (b), and (c) are clear to me.

How to show part (d)?

Let $V$ be an open set in $A$, let $x \in f(V)$, and let $a \in V$ such that $x = f(a)$. Since $a \in V$, there is some basis element $\cap_{i=1}^n f_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(U_{\alpha_i})$ (i.e. a finite intersection of element of $\mathcal{S}$) such that $$a \in \cap_{i=1}^n f_{\alpha_i}^{-1}(U_{\alpha_i}) \subset V.$$ Here $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are distinct indices and $U_{\alpha_i}$ is open in $X_{\alpha_i}$ for each $i$. Let's take $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all other indices $\alpha \in J$. Thus,
$$a \in \cap_{\alpha \in J} \ f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha) \subset V.$$
So $$x= f(a) \in \prod_{\alpha \in J}  U_\alpha,$$ which is open in the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. So $$x \in f(V) \cap \left( \prod_{\alpha \in J}  U_\alpha \right) \subset Z \cap \left( \prod_{\alpha \in J}  U_\alpha \right) . $$

Is my reasoning correct so far? If so, then what next?

Comment: (b) is false as stated, you only have a subbase. You need to add finite intersections of those sets to get a base.

Comment: Show $f \left[\cap_{i=1}^n f_{\alpha_i}^{-1}[U_{\alpha_i}] \right]$ is exactly the product set (with the other $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$) intersected with $Z$. Then $f$ is open in base elements and so open for all, as images preserve unions.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've edited the post. Could you please elaborate the second comment of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct so far. The crucial observation is that the last set in your post is just the image of the basis element of $A$ under $f$, so
$$ 
\textstyle
f(a)\in Z\cap\prod_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha = f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)\right) \subseteq f(V)$$ That means $f(V)$ is open in the relative topology of $Z$.